# "No root filesystem defined" while installing Ubuntu on Virtual box

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, virtualbox, windows-7

I continuously get the error "No root System defined" in the last installation step, and it asks for partitioning, but under the condition of erasing everything on the disk!!!

How should I proceed?

Comment: This isn't a question...

Answer (score 1):

By "Erase and use the entire disk" it means the *virtual hard disk* created before proceeding with the installation XD *not* the Host Computer's actual HDD!
Thanks to [this article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/130922-linux-install-windows-7-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox.html) for the information.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

When you make your VirtualBox VM, make sure that the Hard Drive is set to SATA Slot 0, or IDE Slot 0, that may be causing this. Also install using the defaults from the CD, and it should not have a problem.

If it says "No Root System", that means you need to go to the partition part of the installer and make a root partition SLASH /

For example:

**/  <-- this is the root required, make it like 20 or 30g or more**

**swap <--- this is swap required**

As long as at least these 2 are in the partition tool, it should install ok :)